# SQL query won't return zero after counting

Tags: sql

I'm new to SQL and need to return the number of employees for each office who started in 2018 or later. The result should include zero for the office that doesn't have any employees who started after 01/01/2018.

```
Employees
---------------------------------
|id|office_id|name    |start_date|
---------------------------------|
|1 | 1       | Kyle   |2018-08-08|
|2 | 1       | Sarah  |2017-02-28|
|3 | 3       | Moe    |2019-01-01|
|4 | 3       | Adi    |2018-11-04|
|5 | 3       | Kwun   |2016-05-22|
---------------------------------


Offices
---------
|id|name |
---------|
|1 | CHI |
|2 | NYC |
|3 | LA  |
---------
```

This returns the correct count, but I need it to return zero for office id #2 (NYC). What am I missing?

```
SELECT o.id, COUNT(e.id) AS NumberOfEmployees
FROM Offices AS o
LEFT JOIN Employees as e 
  ON office_id = o.id
WHERE start_date >= '2018-01-01'
GROUP BY o.id
```

Comment: What is the output/expect output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to move `start_date >= '2018-01-01'` condition into the left join. That way, office with no employees will be visible:

```
SELECT o.id, COUNT(e.id) AS NumberOfEmployees
FROM Offices AS o
LEFT JOIN Employees as e 
  ON office_id = o.id 
      AND start_date >= '2018-01-01'
GROUP BY o.id
```